# Which AWS key access for informatica install

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, informatica, informatica-powerexchange

I'm a novice to AWS and Informatica Developer. I have an access key ID and a password to log in to the AWS console and an access key ID and a password to use the AWS API. and Informatica wants to install its services in this aws account. so I would like to know what identifiers I have to provide informatica, those of AWS console or AWS API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on below Article:

https://kb.informatica.com/proddocs/Product%20Documentation/6/PWX_102_AmazonS3UserGuideForPowerCenter_en.pdf

Informatica requires API keys (access and secret keys) to make REST API calls.
It doesn't require console username and password. The IAM user should have the appropriate permissions.